# Page not found error after editing for placement in a queue

Tags: bug, edits

I'm not sure if my edit for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46504/how-to-create-an-encrypted-container-dinamically-expendable) has been placed in a queue or not.

Upon editing, I get redirected to https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/46504/edit-submit/bc241b24-1714-4d34-993b-e11e7743eef2

which says "Page not found".

Looking at the original question, I *don't* see the usual

> Thanks for your edit! This edit will be visible only to you until it
>   is peer reviewed.

or my changes. However, the edit link is grayed out, with tooltip `Another edit has already been suggested`.

Could this situation arise if another low-rep user suggests an edit during my editing process? If so, it would be nice if this was handled with something more graceful than a 404...

Note: [An edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/46504/revisions) from another low-rep user has just appeared.

Comment: I got this bug too; it happened to me after I improved a suggested edit and it was approved while I was improving it.